# Ruby Nil and Zero

Tags: ruby

What's the science behind the fact that the to_i method in Ruby's NilClass instances returns zero? Returning *nil* or raising an exception would not be more logical?

Comment: Related: You can use `n = Integer(str)` if you want to raise an exception on failure.

Comment: 0 is the numerical expression of nil. It represents the absents of something. I have 0 banana's is the same as I have nil banana's. That I believe is the logic behind it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NilClass` defines `#to_i` for the same reason it defines a `#to_a` that returns `[].` It's giving you something of the right type but an empty sort of value.

This is actually quite useful. For example:

```
<%= big.long.expr.nil? ? "" : big.long.expr %>
```

becomes:

```
<%= big.long.expr %>
```

Much nicer!  (Erb is calling #to_s which, for nil, is "".) And:

```
if how.now.brown.cow && how.now.brown.cow[0]
  how.now.brown.cow[0]
else
  0
end
```

becomes:

```
how.now.brown.cow.to_a[0].to_i
```

The short conversions exist when only a representation is needed. The long conversions are the ones that the Ruby core methods call and they require something very close. Use them if you want a type check.

That is:

```
thing.to_int # only works when almost Integer already. NilClass throws NoMethodError

thing.to_i # this works for anything that cares to define a conversion
```

Comment: *"Much nicer!"* Yeah, that depends on how well you and anyone else working on the project knows Ruby and how much you want to rely on unintuitive behavior.  `nil.to_i` returning 0 instead of raising an exception doesn't make a lot of sense logically.  How can you get `0` from `nil`?  It's not like `nil == 0` returns true either, yet `to_i` implies an equivalency.

Comment: @Ed S.: No, `to_int` implies an equivalency, `to_i` is so lax, it really doesn't imply much of anything.

Comment: great answer! I always overlooked the long conversions, now I can understand they and how the fit in the ruby's philosophy.

Answer (score 16):

It fits the Ruby philosophy of permissiveness (as opposed to, for example, the strictness of Python):

```
nil.to_i #=> 0 
"".to_i #=> 0
"123hello".to_i #=> 123
"hello".to_i #=> 0
```

As noted by Zabba, you can use [Kernel#Integer(string)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) for strict conversion.

Comment: You do not need to use regex. If you want errors when a string is not completely a number (such as "123hello"), you can do it like this: `Integer("123hello")` (throws an `ArgumentError`).

Answer (score 9):

`to_i` means "convert me to an integer if you can".

If you want "if you're very much integer-like, give me your integer value, else give a NoMethodError", then use `.to_int`.

There's another question that asks about the difference between `to_i` and `to_int`, `to_s` versus `to_str`, etc. Let me know if you'd like me to find it for you.

Answer (score 6):

The protocol of `to_i` says that you *must* return an `Integer` and you *must not* raise an exception. Both of your suggestions violate at least one of those rules. So, no, those would not only not be more logical, they would be simply invalid.

Note, however, that `nil` *does not* respond to `to_int`. If it *did* respond to `to_int`, that would, indeed, be "illogical".

Comment: The fact that the protocol says that `to_i` must return an integer doesn't make this behavior logical, it just makes it conformant (given, it's better to be conformant even if illogical.)

Answer (score 6):

If you happen to be in Rails then you can use `try`:

```
nil.to_i # => 0
nil.try :to_i # => nil
```

Answer (score 4):

A concise Ruby 2.3+ method for returning `nil` for `nil.to_i` instead of 0, is to use the [safe navigation operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator):

```
irb(main):001:0> nil.to_i
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> nil&.to_i
=> nil
```